# Abs method in emgucv 3.X

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, absolute-value, sobel

I use C# and EmguCV 3.X. I need Abs method for Sobel method to make postive `negative edges`. Is there any method like Abs() in emgucv 3.x? Processing time is very important for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Math.Abs()` should work.

Comment: Are you using Mat or Image<TColor,TDepth> ?

Answer (score 0):

EmguCV is an OpenCV wrapper which also wraps OpenCV's `abs()` function to calculate the absolute of each pixels value in an image.

For single values just use C#'s `Math.Abs()`